# Find specific value in comma list in database

Tags: php, mysql, list

In one of my tables, I have a column where it has a comma-separated list of users that have bought that item. [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MMm9.png)

How can I read the list and run a PHP script to find if the user that is logged in (that is stored in the Session) is in that list. For example, how could I see if the logged on user (MTNOfficial) is in the list. I think it's a PHP if statement with a MySQL CONCAT or FIELD_IN_SET or something.

Comment: I need it to be in a php if statement to say IF the user that is logged in is in the list, then, else....

Comment: Please provide your code instead of explanations of your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to find the records that contain your user

```
select *
from your_table
where find_in_set('MTNOfficial', usersBought) > 0
```

Comment: How do  check to see if the user exists in a php if statement

Comment: You can ask another question about it here on Stack Overflow. But when you do give context and detail what you want to do and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Get the comma separated list, then try the php function explode() to get an array that you can loop over.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$target = "MTNOfficial";
$query = "select usersBought from table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $users = explode("," $row['usersBought']);
    // may want to trim() here
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); i++) {
        if ($users[i] == $target) {
            //we found him!
        }
    }
}
```